# Test class error: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Same value: null

Tags: apex, unit-test, community, error

I am running the following test class:

---

```
@isTest
public class testUserRoot {

    @isTest
    static void testSelfRegisterSuccessRunAs(){
        UserRoot.UserCreateRequest ucReq;
        UserRoot.UserCreateResponse ucRes;
        Id guID = [SELECT GuestUserId FROM Site WHERE UrlPathPrefix = 'TESLA' LIMIT 1].GuestUserId;
        System.runAs(new User(Id = guID)){
            RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
            RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
            req.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/IdPUser';
            req.httpMethod = 'POST';
            req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            RestContext.request = req;
            RestContext.response= res;
            ucReq = new UserRoot.UserCreateRequest();
            ucReq.firstname = 'Name';
            ucReq.lastname = 'Surnname';
            ucReq.phone = '1234567890';
            ucRes = UserRoot.selfRegister(ucReq);
              
    }  
    System.assertNotEquals(null, ucRes.userId);  
        }
}
```

---

It gives me error: `System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Same value: null`

---

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at just the test class isn't going to be enough to go by. Please edit your post to include the class that you're testing as well.

Comment: Line 6 appears to be incorrect; you can't reference ucReq before it is defined, and even if you could, it is apparently null at this point. Something is wrong with your code.

Comment: @sfdcfox Fixed the code. Can you please re-check?

Comment: Better, though as Nicholas suggests, can you share the code you're testing? (at least, the relevant bits?) I don't see any real reason why the assert would fail here, it might be based on your input parameters.

Comment: @sfdcfox Added. Can you check please?

Answer (score 1):

You're only setting a `userId` if `ipAddress.size() > 0`, but you're not inserting any `Black_IP___c` records in your test. Apex Test methods only have access to data created in the same method or data created in a method in the same test class that's annotated with `@TestSetup`. If you change the annotation for your test method, to `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`, you'll be able to query for all org data, but this can lead to unpredictability in tests if you're not careful.

The best option for you would be to create a `Black_IP___c` record in your test method and set a matching `remoteAddress` in the same method to allow for predictability in this test.